# Get max score and store in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is my table:

| student_id | subject_id | total | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 90 |  |
| 102 | 2 | 80 |  |
| 103 | 1 | 95 |  |
| 101 | 1 | 82 |  |
| 103 | 2 | 76 |  |
| 104 | 1 | 95 |  |
| 101 | 2 | 71 |  |

I want to get the max total in a particular subject and store it in another column whenever the total column is inserted or updated.

This is what I want the table to look like:

| student_id | subject_id | total | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 90 | 95 |
| 102 | 2 | 80 | 80 |
| 103 | 1 | 95 | 95 |
| 101 | 1 | 82 | 95 |
| 103 | 2 | 76 | 80 |
| 104 | 1 | 95 | 95 |
| 101 | 2 | 71 | 80 |

I have tried this query but it doesn't add the max scores in each subject against all the student_id.

```
SELECT MAX(`total`) AS highest 
FROM results 
GROUP BY student_id
```

I suppose I should use a trigger for this but the normal query is also okay by me.

Comment: can you share the DBMS you're using?

Comment: DBMS? I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm assuming you're using either mysql or mariadb as long as only those two are supported by phpmyadmin (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL 8+.

Ideally, instead of storing MaxTotal data into each column, you should get such the data while selecting like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT subject_id,MAX(total) AS MaxTotal
FROM results
GROUP BY subject_id
)
SELECT results.*,CTE.MaxTotal
FROM results
JOIN CTE ON results.subject_id = CTE.subject_id;
```

However, if you still need to update it anyway, use `UPDATE` with `JOIN`

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT subject_id,MAX(total) AS MaxTotal
FROM results
GROUP BY subject_id
)
UPDATE results 
JOIN CTE ON results.subject_id = CTE.subject_id
SET results.MaxTotal = CTE.MaxTotal;
```

Output after the update:

| student_id | subject_id | total | MaxTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 90 | 95 |
| 102 | 2 | 80 | 80 |
| 103 | 1 | 95 | 95 |
| 101 | 1 | 82 | 95 |
| 103 | 2 | 76 | 80 |
| 104 | 1 | 95 | 95 |
| 101 | 2 | 71 | 80 |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf0d929e7715ea2095e8c4bd8a0ccc84).

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually need the SELECT statement. It worked very fine.

Comment: But do you know how I can go about this if I want to set a trigger?

Comment: Since any change (insert/update of total field) can affect any number of rows, you will have to perform an update query which I mentioned in the answer for each change (for specific subject Id). I will not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If your column does not yet exist in your table, you need to add it with an `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table_name> ADD max INT;
```

Then you can first select the "*max*" value for each "*subject_id*" using an aggregation, then use it inside the `UPDATE` statement exploiting a `JOIN` operation:

```
UPDATE     <your_table_name>
INNER JOIN (SELECT subject_id, 
                   MAX(total) AS total_max
            FROM <your_table_name>
            GROUP BY subject_id) cte
        ON <your_table_name>.subject_id = cte.subject_id
SET <your_table_name>.max = cte.total_max;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnhUYznFSaPrNdp6uFpV9V/0).